# Junit test case failure due to object mismatch

Tags: java, junit

Here's my code

```
 public static void updateCourseById(String course, Integer id) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = getInstance();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(DSJNDINAME);
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setCatalog(course);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(UPDATE_COURSE_BY_ID);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException | NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        //clear resources
    }
}
```

And the corresponding JUnit test case is below

```
public void testUpdateCourseById() throws SQLException, NamingException {
    InitialContext initialContext = mock(InitialContext.class);
    DataSource dataSource = mock(DataSource.class);
    Connection connection = mock(Connection.class);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = mock(PreparedStatement.class);
    StudentService studentService = mock(StudentService.class);
    doReturn(initialContext).when(studentService).getInstance();
    when(initialContext.lookup(DSJNDINAME)).thenReturn(dataSource);
    when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
    when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);
    studentService.updateCourseById(COURSE, 123);
    verify(connection).setCatalog(COURSE);
    verify(preparedStatement).setInt(1, 123);
    verify(preparedStatement).executeUpdate();
}
```

Getting the below exception

> Wanted but not invoked:
> connection.setCatalog("course");
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

DSJNDINAME, UPDATE_COURSE_BY_ID and COURSE are string constants.
Somewhere there is a mismatch of the object. Could someone please help ?

Comment: `StudentService` itself is a mock, obviously you can't verify anything that happens in `updateCourseById`, since it never happens. You need to create the instance of `StudentService` using the mocks. And `Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, etc., are all local variables, mocking instances won't work, you need to 1) mock the creation of those types or 2) refactor your code in a way that allows testing - currently `updateCourseById` does way too many things - initializing connection, building and executing query, cleaning resources.